# Wrap all images in html string with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

looked around and couldn't find anything that helps

I need a function that replaces all images in a string with wrapped images with matching href then returns a string.

```
content = "<html>";
var $content = $(content);
$('img', $content).each(function () {
        $(this).html().replace($(this).html(),'<a href="' + $(this).attr('src') + '" target="_blank" class="thumbnailLink"><img src="' + $(this).attr('src') + '" style="' + $(this).attr('style') +'"></a>')                    
    }); 
    return  $content.html();
```

Comment: jQuery methods will not work on a string, BUT, if you can append() string to body, to one hidden element, and simple wrap() images, you can easily get modified html() and return string? (if i understand your request at all, not sure about context, anyway)

Comment: @nevermind you undersand the  request, yes that may be the issue here. does var $content = $(content); not create a dom element that can be manipulated?

Comment: @Jermy Nelson, it creates jQuery object, yes, but not DOM element (i think)...Here is (could be) workaround: https://jsfiddle.net/g4ufscha/

Comment: Anyway, i think i got it, you were right, implementation was wrong...

Answer (score 1):

Here is possible solution, hope it will work for you.

```
content = '<div class="img"><img src="fjords.jpg" alt="Fjords" width="300" height="200"><div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div></div><div class="img"><img src="forest.jpg" alt="Forest" width="300" height="200"><div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div></div><div class="img"><img src="lights.jpg" alt="Northern Lights" width="300" height="200"><div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div></div><div class="img"><img src="mountains.jpg" alt="Mountains" width="300" height="200"><div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div></div>';
html = $( content );


$('img',html).each(function () {
$(this).wrap('<a href="' + $(this).attr('src') + '" target="_blank" class="thumbnailLink"> </a>');    

    }); 
final=[];
$.each(html, function(index, value) {
    final.push($(value).html());
}); 

console.log(final.join(''));
```

So, simple wrap images inside $content, and then iterate through object, make jQuery object from value, to get html(), and output final string.

DEMO>https://jsfiddle.net/vaxL8d9p/1/

Answer (score 0):

You could just set the `html` instead of reading and replacing it.

```
$('img', $content).each(function () {
    var src = $(this).attr('src');
    var style = $(this).attr('style');
    $(this).html('<a href="' + src + '" target="_blank" class="thumbnailLink"><img src="' + src + '" style="' + style +'"></a>'); 
});
```

Comment: sorry this does not work. returning  $content.html() will only have 1 image

Comment: @JeremyNelson The above snippet is supposed to be inside the `$.each` block

Comment: yes, i'm finding $(this).html is empty at all times